# Handling Database: Good software engineering concepts

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

When I am creating JDBC application, what I normally do is, hard coding the "sql statements" to the java program. For an example

```
ResultSet rs = st.execute("select * from Users")
```

But, I have heard that this approach is not good software engineering concept. Some say all these sql statements should stay on database as "stored procedures" and JDBC should access them. From these two approaches, which can be categorized as a good software engineering concept? Please help!

Comment: Are you sure that you really mean "stored procedures"? Chances are you might be interested in "prepared statements" that prevent you from SQL injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't find concensus on this, I predict.

Stored procs are useful for encapsulating complex database logic and queries whilst avoiding transferring the data out of the database in order to sort/filter/query etc.

The downside is that you often find business logic creeping into stored procedures whereas it should likely remain in the application itself.

So there's often a *tug-of-war* between developers/dbas etc as to where this logic should reside and how to use stored procs. I would suggest being pragmatic. Localise your SQL queries so that when you change the SQL (table-names etc.) you don't have to change stuff across your entire codebase. Make use of stored procs for performance and when you're doing stuff that is complex in code, but trivial for the database.

Comment: imagine something like this: you need to get the answer of (priceColumn*quantityColumn)*2 . THe value "2" doesn't change bcs it is the algorithm. In this case, what is best?

Comment: @Yohan - I would *perhaps* do that within the business logic of the app, and move it to the database if that table was sizable and the number of rows prohibited efficient xfer to the app. As I say, there are no right/wrong answers here

Comment: @Yohan - I would be very reluctant to dismiss this as 'very wrong'. I think it's close to a performance-type and/or company-policy type issue. Note that in Oracle (dunno about others) you can define a virtual column which calculates itself on the fly, so it looks like a column but isn't an actual column. So that's a third option. Your best bet in these circumstances is to discuss all your options and the pros/cons.

Comment: awesome! Why I asked that question is, this. I went to an interview.He asked me to create a JDBC app within 30 minutes(how come???), which was given to me by him. I used this same function inside the app (actually, it is not even changeable like this, I had to get 2 values from 2 columns and multiply by 2). He told me I have done a very very wrong thing, I have to put a stored proc, and pass the values to DB. I doubted about this because he got shocked when I asked for "query analyzer" in MSSQL!

Answer (score 2):

Using hard coded String and passing them in `Statement` is certainly not a good software engineering practice.

You should always use `PreparedStatement`

Example:

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME FROM DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL );
```

Stored Procedures are also good practice. Mostly, Stored Procedures are more used as performance perspective as your queries are pre-compiled for except first run.

Comment: You say that, but in the OP's question he gives an unparameterised example in his execute() statement, which looks fine to me

Comment: @BrianAgnew: True,But It is for an example. We might not know that its the only type of SQL query OP is going to execute. So, I wrote to make OP aware

Answer (score 2):

It will be a good practice to use functions or stored procedures in database which returns `SYS_REFCURSOR` and call these from java using `CallableStatement`

If you are using Oracle database, you could try the following

**Database Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func (p_deptno IN number,p_emp_no IN varchar2)
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
   p_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN p_cursor FOR
      select *
        from emp
        where deptno = p_deptno and emp_number=p_emp_no;
   RETURN p_cursor;
END;
/
```

**Java**

```
        callablestatement = 
                connection.prepareCall("begin ? :=my_func(?,?); end;");
callablestatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
callablestatement.setString(2, param);
callablestatement.setString(3, param);
            callablestatement.execute();
            resultSet = ((OracleCallableStatement)callablestatement).getCursor(1);
```

With this approach you could avoid hard coding of sql statement in java.

Comment: You say that, but what's your reasoning ?

Comment: I am trying to suggest ways of avoiding hard coded sql statements in java. By doing so how it would become something which is not related to question? Person who asks question should say that this is not related to question or not rather than giving opinions about other person's suggestions and answers.

Comment: @Polappan: Not hard feelings. I can delete my comment. Nothing is personal here

Comment: @HardikMishra Deleted my comments as well. No issues.

Answer (score 2):

Use Hibernate http://www.hibernate.org/ (or another ORM) so that you do not need to maintain so many SQL statements.
Hibernate generates most of the SQL in the background for you so that you don't need to worry about maintaining SQL statements.

Other ORMs are available too such as TopLink and OpenJPA

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to store all SQL queries as constants:

```
public static final String sqlEmpInsert = "SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES";
```

in a separate java class. I am having separate "constants" class file for each modules and for some modules I'm storing SQL Queries in separate property files, so that it will be segregated from java class files.

Answer (score 1):

If you hard code the SQL-statements you may have to change them in the source code every time you change something in your database.

By using stored procedures you only have to change these and the source code of your java program does not need to be changed.

I would therefore recommend using stored procedures.

Comment: Source code does not required to be change in case when there is no parameter change. But Let say if you are passing parameters to SP from JDBC then change at both need to be changed

Comment: By using SP you do not need to know the structure of the DB(table name, column name,...) in the java program. Changes to these will only need changes to the SP and not to the java program.